# Windows guest fails to boot after enabling 'Enabled Nested VT-x/AMD-V' in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, ubuntu-22.04

I'm running Windows 10 guest machine on Ubuntu 22.04 host and it works fine. I'd like to try WSL2, which needs nested virtualization. The Windows guest fails to boot after I enable nested virtualization.

[image: Windows 10 Boot Failure]

The issue resolves If I turn off nested virtualization.

Let me know if any more info is required to debug the issue.

Comment: Your Windows 10 VM needs to be repaired. I am not certain why it screwed up, but you need to repair or rebuild it.

Comment: @John Thank you for your comment. I have already tried repairing, but it just doesn't work. I even tried to create a new machine while 'Enabled Nested VT-x/AMD-V' is pre-enabled, but I failed to install the OS.

Comment: @John I tried repairing a while ago. I try to perform it again and share the details on why it fails.

Comment: You might try using VMware Workstation as a better and more reliable way to work with nesting.

Comment: @John Currently giving VMware Workstation a shot. I have tried KVM/QEMU via Gnome Boxes and it works with no problem.

Comment: VMware is more user friendly and flexible than QEMU